# elisp debugging, show backtrace when function fails

Tags: debugging, emacs, backtrace

I'd like to see the backtrace of error when I run this code.

```
 (make-network-process :name (dbgp-make-listner-name 10004)
                       :server 1
                       :service 10004
                       :family 'ipv4
                       :nowait t
                       :noquery t
                       :filter 'dbgp-comint-setup
                       :sentinel 'dbgp-listener-sentinel
                       :log 'dbgp-listener-log)
```

https://github.com/gregsexton/ob-ipython/issues/4
This shows that I can see what's going on under `make-network-process`.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "make client process failed" "connection refused" :name "localhost" :buffer # :host "localhost" :service 9988 :nowait nil)
make-network-process(:name "localhost" :buffer # :host "localhost" :service 9988 :nowait nil)
open-network-stream("localhost" # "localhost" 9988 :type plain :nowait nil)
byte-code . . . 
url-open-stream("localhost" # "localhost" 9988)
url-http-find-free-connection("localhost" 9988)
url-http([cl-struct-url "http" nil nil "localhost" 9988 "/execute/default" nil nil t nil t] #128 "\302\303\304p#\210\300\305\240\210\301p\240\207" [(nil) (nil) url-debug retrieval "Synchronous fetching done (%S)" t] 5 "\n\n(fn &rest IGNORED)")
url-retrieve-internal("http://localhost:9988/execute/default" #128 "\302\303\304p#\210\300\305\240\210\301p\240\207" [(nil) (nil) url-debug retrieval "Synchronous fetching done (%S)" t] 5 "\n\n(fn &rest IGNORED)" nil nil)
url-retrieve("http://localhost:9988/execute/default" #[128
```

I tried

`toggle-debug-on-error`
`edebug-eval-defun`

But I can't see the backtrace..

on `*Backtrace*` buffer, I can see

```
Debugger entered: nil
  (progn (debug) (make-network-process :name (dbgp-make-listner-name 10004) :server 1 :service 10004 :family (quote ipv4) :nowait t :noquery t :filter (quote dbgp-comint-setup) :sentinel (quote dbgp-listener-sentinel) :log (quote dbgp-listener-log)))
  eval((progn (debug) (make-network-process :name (dbgp-make-listner-name 10004) :server 1 :service 10004 :family (quote ipv4) :nowait t :noquery t :filter (quote dbgp-comint-setup) :sentinel (quote dbgp-listener-sentinel) :log (quote dbgp-listener-log))) nil)
  edebug-eval-defun(nil)
  apply(edebug-eval-defun nil)
  eval-defun(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-defun nil)
  call-interactively(eval-defun record nil)
  command-execute(eval-defun record)
  helm-M-x(nil "eval-defun")
  funcall-interactively(helm-M-x nil "eval-defun")
  call-interactively(helm-M-x nil nil)
  command-execute(helm-M-x)
```

While the first trace shows what's going on behind `make-network-process`, my trace doesn't go deeper..

Comment: You say you can't see a backtrace, and then you show us the backtrace that you can see. Please clarify?

Comment: @phils: I added the other traceback, it goes below `make-network-process` . I know `make-network-process` fails, want to find out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the question is how to get *more detail* in the backtrace.

For byte-compiled elisp functions, loading the *uncompiled* version of the library in question will generally give you more detail, as the debugger can then show you *exactly where* in the function things happened.

However in this instance, `make-network-process` is a C function, so what you see now is all you're going to get out of the elisp debugger.

You'll have to examine/debug the source code in process.c if you want to know more.

Comment: So how does he see the C function's backtrace `byte-code` part.? https://github.com/gregsexton/ob-ipython/issues/4

Comment: What do you mean? The backtrace on that page goes no further than your own, stopping at the call to `make-network-process`. C functions have no byte code (by definition, given that they're not elisp).

Comment: Note that the stack frames are shown from newest to oldest (top to bottom) in the backtrace. The first thing shown after the error is the most recent call, from which the error was triggered. The frames below that are the events leading up to that point.